# Generate FFI call using Template Haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, haskell-frames

In the [Frames library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Frames), one has a `readTable` function, that generates a record type based on a CSV file.

Is it possible to generate a call like `foreign import ccall unsafe "// c code" c_foo :: Int -> IO ()`?

I've tried to accomplish so using a `[d| ... |]` and a `[t| ... |]` quasiquoters, but in both I get a parser error.

Comment: It is possible. `[d| foreign import ccall unsafe "malloc" c_malloc :: Int -> IO () |]`, for example, works. There are some examples of template Haskell with FFI [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foreign_Function_Interface#Inline_FFI_calls). Note also that this is exactly what [inline-c](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/inline-c) and [inline-java](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/inline-java) rely on.

Comment: @Alec could you make this an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The error message you are seeing is due to `"// c code"` being a "Malformed entity string". Anything more sane, and you are off to the races:

```
ghci> :set -XTemplateHaskell
ghci> ffi = [d| foreign import ccall unsafe "foo" c_foo :: Int -> IO () |]
```

[Here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foreign_Function_Interface#Inline_FFI_calls) is an example which does pretty much exactly what you are asking about. Note that both the packages [inline-c](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/inline-c) and [inline-java](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/inline-java) rely on this sort of thing.

Comment: "// c code" was just a place holder I wrote here, anyways, thanks for the answer it really helped me :)